# how to solve: $\tan 2x=\tan x$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

**Question**

how to solve: $\tan 2x=\tan x$

At first by speculation I realized that if $x$ was $2$ and $0$ it would satisfy the question, but then I heard that the solution was $k\pi$ when $k$ is an integer.

How do I figure out that the solution to the problem is $k\pi$?

Comment: Do u know $\tan y=\tan A, y=n\pi+A$

Comment: Do you know how to express $\tan 2x$ in terms of $\tan x$, or the double-angle formulae for $\sin$ and $\cos$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tangent is periodic with period $\pi$, so we have
$$\tan(a)=\tan(b) \iff b=n\pi+a$$
In this case we find that $2x = n\pi + x \implies x=n\pi$

Comment: If $f$ is periodic of period $T$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ does not imply $b=a+n\,T$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. What can you say about two angles $A$ and $B$ if $\tan A = \tan B$? Looking at the graph of the tangent function may help you answer this question.